# $f$ don't have local minimum or local maximum in $c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

if $f$ is a function, with derivate of order $n$ on $(a,b)$, and $c \in (a,b)$ such that $c$ is a critical point, where:
\begin{eqnarray}
 f'(c)=0, f''(c)=0, \dots, f^{(n-1)}(c)=0, f^{(n)} (c) \neq 0
\end{eqnarray}
then for odd order, $f$ don't have a local minimum and local maximum in $c$.

---

I've tried by definition of limits and analyse the signs of some $x$ in the interval $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ for $\delta >0$ on $2n-1$ derivate, but I'm stuck, Do you know some way to do this? Can I continue by this way?

Comment: What about $f(x)=x^n$ or $f(x)=x^{n+1}$ and $c=0$?

Comment: I have to edit the post, I have other condition ,$f^{(n)}(c) \neq 0$

Comment: What is meant by for "odd order"?

Comment: It means that $f^{(n)}(x)$ exist for $x\in (a,b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f^{(n)}$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ this follows form Taylor's Theorem:
Choose $\delta>0$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)f^{(n)}(c)> 0$ $(x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\subseteq (a,b))$. Let $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta) \setminus \{c\}$. Then for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $c$ we have
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^k +\frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}(x-c)^n
=f(c) + \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!}(x-c)^n. 
$$
If $f^{(n)}(c)> 0$, then $f^{(n)}(\xi)> 0$ (since $\xi \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$). Since $n$ is odd $(x-c)^n > 0$ $(x\in (c,c+\delta))$ and $(x-c)^n < 0$ $(x\in (c-\delta,c))$. Thus $f(x) > f(c)$ $(x\in (c,c+\delta))$ and $f(x) < f(c)$ $(x\in (c-\delta,c))$. The case $f^{(n)}(c)< 0$ follows the same way.

If you insist that $f^{(n)}$ only exists (and is allowed to be discontinuous) then I don't know the answer.

Comment: Why $f(x)>f(c)$ ?

Comment: Cause $f(x) = f(c) + $ something $> 0$ if $x \in (c,c+\delta)$.

Comment: Ohh...  thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The function **cannot** have a local maximum or minimum in $c$, even if the last derivative is not continuous. Let us see how to approach the problem without using Taylor's Theorem, which gives you the result only in the case of continuity of the last derivative, as pointed out by [Gerd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/960044/gerd).

I will change a little bit the notation, to make the process clearer.

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on some neighborhood of $0$. Suppose also that the derivatives up to order $2n+1$, for some $n\geq 0$, are defined in that neighborhood. We also have that
> $$f^{(k)}(0) = 0, \ \ \mbox{for}\ \ k=0,1,\dots,2n$$
> and that
> $$f^{(2n+1)}(0) > 0,$$
> where $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$ and $f^{(k)}(x)$ is the $k$-th order derivative of $f$. Then $0$ is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum.

*Note that, with respect to OP statement, but WLOG, we set $c=0$ and $f(c) = 0$.*

**Proof.**

We have that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f^{(2n)}(x)}{x}  = f^{(2n+1)}(0)>0,$$
which implies that there is a neighborhood $\mathcal I$ of $0$ such that
$$\frac{f^{(2n)}(x)}{x}>0\tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $x\in \mathcal I\setminus \{0\}$. If $n=0$, we are done, since \eqref{1} implies the thesis.

Suppose now $n>0$. For each $x\in \mathcal I\setminus \{0\}$ we must have
$$f^{(2n-1)}(x) > 0\tag{2}\label{2}.$$
In fact, suppose there exists $\bar x \in \mathcal I\setminus \{0\}$ such that $f^{(2n-1)}(\bar x)\leq 0$, then by the Mean Value Theorem there would exist $\xi \in \mathcal I\setminus \{0\}$ such that
$$f^{(2n)}(\xi) = \frac{f^{(2n-1)}(0)-f^{(2n-1)}(\bar x)}{0-\bar x}=\frac{f^{(2n-1)}(\bar x)}{\bar x}.$$
If $\bar x <0$, then $\bar x < \xi <0$ and $f^{(2n)}(\xi)\geq 0$. If $\bar x >0$, then $0< \xi <\bar x$, and $f^{(2n)}(\xi)\leq 0$. Both situations contradict \eqref{1}.

Equation \eqref{2} clearly implies that $f^{(2n-2)}(x)$ is monotonically increasing in $\mathcal I$. Since $f^{(2n-2)}(0)=0$ we have therefore
$$\frac{f^{(2n-2)}(x)}{x}>0$$
for $x \in \mathcal I\setminus \{0\}$.

Now it is straightforward to iterate the procedure in order to show that, for $i=1,2\dots n$,
$$f^{(2(n-i)+1)}(x) > 0$$
for $x \in \mathcal I\setminus \{0\}$, and
$$\frac{f^{(2(n-i))}(x)}{x}>0\tag{3}\label{3}$$
for $x\in \mathcal I \setminus \{0\}$. The thesis follows immediately from \eqref{3}, with $i=n$.

Comment: Interesting. Two questions: In line 11 form below shouldn't it be "... and $f^{(2n)}(\xi) > 0$" resp. "... and $f^{(2n)}(\xi) < 0$"? Second, How do you get the strict inequality $\frac{f^{(2n-2)}(x)}{x} > 0$ from "$f^{(2n-2)}$ increasing"?

Comment: @Gerd 1) Yes, thanks I'll correct the mistake. 2) Given the condition $f^{(2n-2)}(0) = 0$, the monotonicity implies that, in $\mathcal I$, $x$ and $f^{(2n-2)}(x)$ have the same sign. Let me know if you find any other incorrect or unclear step.

Comment: I am still struggling with the strict inequality. If $f^{(2n-1)}(x) \ge 0$ on $\mathcal{T}$ why is  $f^{(2n-2)}(x)=0$ for some  $x \in \mathcal{T} \setminus\{0\}$ impossible? I think that you get with the same proof that $f^{(2n-1)}(x) > 0$ on $\mathcal{T} \setminus\{0\}$. Then it would be clear.

Comment: I think I got it: If $f^{(2n-2)}$ would be $0$ on a small intervall right or left of $0$ then $f^{(2n)}$ would be there $0$ too, so $f^{(2n-1)}(x) \ge 0$ is sufficient.

Comment: @Gerd As a matter of fact in (2) a **strict inequality** can be used, since as you say, $f^{(2n)}(\xi) = 0$ at some point in $\mathcal I$ other than $0$ would contradict, too, (1), again by way of the MVT. Thanks for pointing it out! I am going to change the inequalities accordingly. Let me know what you think, if you like.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. Just a typo: In lines 3,16 and 14 form below I think it should then be "...$x \in \mathcal{T} \setminus \{0\}$..." and "...$\overline{x} \in \mathcal{T} \setminus \{0\}$...", respectively. Sorry for the nitpicking.

Comment: @gerd, correct, thanks. With these new inequalities the correction is necessary.

Comment: @gerd I was writing down the details of my proof on my website (noting that, in the conditions given in OP we can actually state that $f$ has a local extremum *if and only if* the first non-null derivative is odd). While doing that I noticed that one could even think of a function where $f^{(n)}$ exists only in $c$, in which case you cannot even use Taylor's Theorem up to order $n-1$. Despite that, the thesis is still valid.

Comment: Yes, right. Differentiability of $f^{(2n)}$ is only needed in $c$. However "if and only if" only if there is a first non-null derivative. There can be a local extremum in $c$ (even strict) and $f^{(k)}(c)=0$ for all $k \ge 1$.